# What is the actual process name when nautilus is copying files?

Tags: process, cp, nautilus

I am copying some files from an external drive to my desktop running Ubuntu. I can see the "File Operations" dialog which shows copying process.

How do I find this particular process in `ps aux | grep` command? I thought it would be some `cp` command but there is no `cp` command running! So how does this copying work? Please provide any pointers.

Comment: There's no reason for it to use `cp` when it can directly use C/C++ functions to do the copying ... the same way `cp` does. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-a-sane-safe-and-efficient-way

Comment: You could look at [`nautilus-file-operations.c`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/tree/libnautilus-private/nautilus-file-operations.c) to see how it works. Nautilus uses [`GIO`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/file_ops.html)  to do this kind of stuff...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process name is `nautilus`. Nautilus contains its own code to copy files, this code is executed inside the nautilus process, not in a subprocess.

You can see for yourself what subprocesses Nautilus runs by logging its system calls with [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace):

```
strace -f -o /tmp/nautilus.strace nautilus
```

The `clone` system call creates new processes (it's a generalization of [`fork`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call))). The `execve` system call runs another program in the same process. Running another program thus entails `clone` followed by `execve`. You can quickly see what programs Nautilus executes (or tries to) with

```
grep execve /tmp/nautilus.strace
```

You'll find that Nautilus creates subprocesses for some things such as previewing the content of certain types of files, but it does the file copying on its own.